# Is there a way to have two link types in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I know this question sounds like it goes against the netlogo paradigm, but 
I'm looking for a way for any two turtles to have more than one type of link. Lets say a blue link and a green link?

Comment: I'm just curious: why did you think it would it go against the NetLogo paradigm to have multiple types of links?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just like turtles, you can have `breeds` of links. The following code has two breeds named green-links and blue-links. In this case, both are `undirected-links` but you can also have `directed-links`.

```
undirected-link-breed [green-links green-link]
undirected-link-breed [blue-links blue-link]

to testme
  clear-all
  ask patches [set pcolor white]
  create-turtles 10
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color red
  ]
  repeat 20
  [ ask one-of turtles
    [ create-green-link-with one-of other turtles [ set color green ] ]
  ]
  repeat 20
  [ ask one-of turtles
    [ create-blue-link-with one-of other turtles [ set color blue ] ]
  ]
end
```

There is nothing stopping the same pair of turtles from having multiple links between them as long as the links are of different `breeds`.